# Android - Attaching info window to a polyline

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, polyline

Is it possible to attach an InfoWindow (or anything like that) to a polyline in Google Map widget?
Like the official Maps app from google, I'm trying to display an info window when the user draws polylines on the map.
In Maps app, when you search for a direction between two places, the app adds an info window (or something like that) to each route!

Answer (score 0):

You can add invisible markers on route and show their info window.
Other option is to draw custom views over map.